# How to log/view all frontend login sessions?

Tags: zoo-visitor, login, sessions

Does EE stores all frontend login actions somewhere?

Checking in Control Panel > Tools > Logs > Control Panel I can see it lists all users that have logged into the CP but not the ones logged in using {exp:member:login_form} or {exp:zoo_visitor:login_form}.

I was thinking of creating an extension that logs all new sessions in a separate table but though it was worth asking here just in case is there an easier way.

Cheers,
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control Panel Logs is existed not just to show logged users but logged all critical activities(not only login) in CP. EE keeps this records in _cp_log table.

For front-end is not such functions from the box.

But you can try module called [Audit Pro](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit-pro)

> Audit tracks:
>
> Member Logins, including Control Panel & **front-end**
>
> Member Logouts, including Control Panel & **front-end**
>
> New Entries, including Safecracker
>
> Updates to Entries, via the Publish screen or multiple entries via the >Edit screen, including Safecracker
>
> Deleting Entries
>
> New Members
>
> Deleting Members
>
> Editing of Members
>
> Changing Templates (editing a template, not its preferences)

Comment: Great, thanks Max! Audit Pro works like a treat for this specific needs